# Bug with Delvin and Vex and their Dialogue?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Every time I reload Skyrim on PC, Delvin and Vex have their dialogue reset, where the dialogue option is "I Heard you are offering Extra Work"?

It's really annoying, especially how since all of the special quest dialogues reset too, I have experienced the issue on the standard edition on XBOX 360, and the Special Edition on PC.

I have tried the `ResetAI` command and the `disable` then `enable` command, but none of them work.

Comment: What are you expecting their dialog to be?  Is it causing any problems with any of your quests?  Did you even join the thieves guild?  (Yes, it is possible to get there during the main quest.)

Comment: It's not causing any issues per say, but it is really annoying to sit through the introductory dialogue for the jobs everytime I boot up the game again.

What i expected (and i believe i remember from a previous playthrough on ps3) was for their dialogue to be as if i had talked to them already, so they don't explain what each type of job was again (i.e like explaining how a burglary job works)

And yes, I did join the thieves guild, otherwise, i couldn't get the dialogue to do the jobs (i suppose i didn't explain it perfectly)

Comment: This seems to be listed as a known issue on the [UESP wiki](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Bugs), but it unfortunately doesn't provide a solution, even on the [discussion page section](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#As_If_I_Hadn.27t_Done_Any_Jobs).

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean, thanks for that! At least I know!~

Answer (score 1):

Did you try recycle actor? That resets them and they will spawn in their normal spoto and should help with the dialog.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What do you mean by recycle actor? It might be a good idea to expand on that in your answer, and describe how OP might be able to do that.

Comment: Despawn them and re-spawn them